# The probability of having disease is 0.1%; the test for it has 99% accuracy. What is the probability of having the disease given positive test result?

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian

I got this question from an interview and failed to give an answer. I have been thinking about this for a while and would love some help. I think we have the following:

P(D (disease)) = 0.1%,
P(TP or TN) = 99%

And we want to know the following:

P(D | P)

which can be translated to: P(D and P)/P(P) or P(TP)/P(TP or FP). It seems impossible to maneuver the known to get to the unknown.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Hint: rather than P(TP or TN), think about P(positive test | D) and P(positive Test | not-D). Then add Bayes' Theorem.

Comment: Note that a test could have $99.9\%$ accuracy if it predicted “no disease” every time. That the given test has lower accuracy than this might suggest a low probability of having the disease. (I think I would like to hear a comment like that on an interview.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I am confused. How do you convert accuracy to P(Pos | D) and P(Pos | ~D)? If the accuracy of 99% meant that P(Pos | D) = 99% and that P(Pos | ~D) = 1%, then the problem would be straightforward, the answer would be P(Pos|D) * P(D) / [P(Pos|D) * P(D) + P(Pos|~D) * P(~D)] = about 9.1%. But I don't think that's the case as accuracy should mean P(Pos & D) OR P(~Pos & ~D).

Comment: Presumably by "accuracy" they mean *both* specificity and sensitivity are 99%. This is a common thing in toy questions like this. In an interview, you can always seek clarification about intent.

Comment: I am guessing you are right, @Glen_b. I think it'd be a classical toy stat question if the "accuracy" simply meant P(Pos | D) = 99% and that P(Pos | ~D) = 1%. Otherwise, as Björn put it, it would yield no exact answers and probably not relevant for an interview question. I should have clarified.

Comment: I checked with the interviewer, though perhaps I shouldn't, but you are right @Glen_b. The question implicitly assumed equal specificity and sensitivity of 99%.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the question can be answered with a precise number with the given information, but you can give a range.

Observe that accuracy = TP + TN = 99% and prevalence = TP + FN = 0.1% still permits lots of possible still permits lots of different situations. E.g. with

- TP = 0%, FN=0.1%, TN = 99%, FP = 0.9%, but also
- TP = 0.1%, FN=0%, TN = 98.9%, FP = 1%.

Your answer is, for each of these scenarios, then easy to calculate, but can vary a good bit.

Comment: Agreed, a range is possible. You could use [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) explicitly to handle the lack of information.